# Type mismatch, opening a RecordSet

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Getting this error all time:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

On this line 
`rs.Open , sqlstr, conn`

I tried everything and can't solve the problem. I'm trying to update one row in MySQL database.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim server_name As String
    Dim database_name As String
    Dim user_id As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim i As Long 
    Dim sqlstr As String 
    Dim table1 As String, table2 As String
    Dim field1 As String, field2 As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim vtype As Variant

    server_name = "99.99.99.99"
    database_name = "name" 
    user_id = "user" 
    password = "pass"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}" _
    & ";SERVER=" & server_name _
    & ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
    & ";UID=" & user_id _
    & ";PWD=" & password _
    & ";OPTION=16427"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    sqlstr = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; UPDATE table SET poslano = 'Poslano' WHERE poslano = 'Neposlano';"

    rs.Open , sqlstr, conn
    With Worksheets("List6").Cells("A1") 
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    skipextract:

    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

    End Sub
```

Comment: Try like this - `rs.Open sqlstr, conn`

Comment: thanks, now im getting another error: "You have an errorr in your SQL synatx; check the manual that corresponds to yout MySql server version for the right syntax to use near UPDATE table SET poslano = 'Poslano' WHERE poslano = "Neposlano" at line 1

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The comma after `rs.Open` makes VBA "think" that the Source is omitted:

[image]

Thus, it gives Type mismatch error. Try to write it like this:

`rs.Open sqlstr, conn`

Comment: thanks, now im getting another error: "You have an errorr in your SQL synatx; check the manual that corresponds to yout MySql server version for the right syntax to use near UPDATE table SET poslano = 'Poslano' WHERE poslano = "Neposlano" at line 1

Comment: @patriot16 - this is a new error, thus it is a good idea to ask a separate question for it. Make sure that you make [mcve] there.